# Why won't my link open in a new tab?

Tags: html

I create websites all the time, but this time I am stumped. I cannot seem to get a link to open in a new tab. Here is the specific line of code I am trying to troubleshoot:

```
<aside id="bnk_widget_donation-2" class="bnk-widget bnk_widget_donation">
    <div class="bnk-donation clickable">
        <span class="donation-icon mobile-hide">&nbsp;</span>
        <h3 class="replace inset">
            <a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=WQZ2PBSENFF2C" target="_blank">
                Donate Now
            </a>
        </h3>
        <p class="subhead">
            support our mission
        </p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

The line number when looking at the source is line 197. The page is available [here](http://www.3e.oneofakind.ws/prayer-ministry/). The problem is the Donate link to PayPal that does not open in a new tab.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is happening when you click on it. The HTML includes a javascript file "http://www.3e.oneofakind.ws/wp-content/themes/bhinneka/js/p2-init.js?ver=3.6" which has a click event `$(".clickable, .landing-mod")`.